# How can I determine the Channel from DriveItem in Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

In SharePoint if I open a folder which happens to be the file folder for a Channel then I see a button titled 'Go to Channel'.

I have looked unsuccessfully for a way to determine the channel that a DriveItem belongs to using the graph api.

I can find the parent folder, and from there the list and list item, which tells me that this folder was created by the Teams App but I do not see how to find which Channel it is related to.

Obviously if I already know the channel I can find its folder using /filesFolder but I want to go the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution would be to:

- [list the team channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-list-allchannels) your MD Graph client has access to
- gather [files folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-files) for each channel (which gives you the drive item ID for team channel folder, so you can build the lookup)
- loop through SharePoint folders and check if the folder exists in the lookup you gathered

NOTE: keeping the Teams channel reference as part of the SharePoint folder object is not right from architectural point of view, because anyone (who can crawl SharePoint structure) in this case could know the fact of some Team channels existence.